# htaccess url redirect to www for any prefix

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site where regardless of what is placed instead of "www", the site still works:

ie. abc.example.com, w.example.com, wwww.example.com, ww.example.com, etc

What I need to do is redirect all of this to the "www" url.

Any help would be of great help

Regards,

Sushil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should rewrite any URL that someone goes to at "example.com" that does not begin with `www` to the URL with the www at the beginning. Note, you may choose to use `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` in the case the mod_rewrite is ever disabled or uninstalled.